# The import org.apache.xml.serialize.XMLSerializer cannot be resolved

Tags: java, jdbc, xerces

When I try to import org.apache.xml.serialize.XMLSerializer, I got the below error msg:

```
 The import org.apache.xml.serialize.XMLSerializer cannot be resolved
```

Can anyone tell me the cause? Thanks!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are missing [xercesImpl-2.9.0.jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/xerces/xercesImpl/2.9.0/xercesImpl-2.9.0.jar) from your build path. If you are using Maven, you can add the dependency:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>xerces</groupId>
   <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
   <version>2.9.0</version>
</dependency>
```